# Video Editing - System Resources not being used

Tags: video, gpu, performance

I need help getting blender to use up more of my system resources to render videos as it never seem to see it use more than 30% of my CPU and my GPU stays on idle (changed settings to use cuda).

It takes about 45min to render a 14min video, which I dont think is bad at all, but since I have a lot of system resources left, it would be nice to render faster.

System specs:

- i5-3570k
- 8gb Ram
- GTX 680 2GB

Answer (score 1):

The video sequencer is doing all its editing in CPU currently (version 2.75). I do have a plan to move some operations to OpenGL. A lot of operations are also not multithreaded. Effect application is multithreaded for instance but scaling images to screen resolution, which is a big computational sink is not.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that will speed it up is clocking up the speed of your memory. The cpu is waiting for data to shift. I have a monster 12 thread CPU and probably take the same time as you.